# SQOOP EXPORT : java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Parameter #1 has not been set

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am trying to do sqoop export to sql server and using the below command:

`sqoop-export -D mapred.job.name=SQOOP:TEST:UPSERT -Dsqoop.export.records.per.statement=1 --connect $CONN --username $USER --password $PWD --table table_test_1 --hcatalog-database default --hcatalog-table test_1 --input-fields-terminated-by '\001' --input-null-string '\\N' --update-key ID --update-mode allowinsert --verbose --columns "name,id,age"`

And I get the below error. Not sure why it says parameter# 1 is not set. If by parameter 1 , sqoop refers to the update-key, which is my `id` here, it is not null in my hive table.
I am using sqoop 1.4

```
16/08/12 11:43:06 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1470577803876_1072_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.io.IOException: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Parameter #1 has not been set.
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AsyncSqlRecordWriter.write(AsyncSqlRecordWriter.java:220)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AsyncSqlRecordWriter.write(AsyncSqlRecordWriter.java:46)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:658)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatExportMapper.map(SqoopHCatExportMapper.java:56)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.hcat.SqoopHCatExportMapper.map(SqoopHCatExportMapper.java:35)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Parameter #1 has not been set.
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeBatch(JtdsStatement.java:1099)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AsyncSqlOutputFormat$AsyncSqlExecThread.run(AsyncSqlOutputFormat.java:231)

16/08/12 11:43:20 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
16/08/12 11:43:20 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1470577803876_1072 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1470577803876_1072_m_000000
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

16/08/12 11:43:20 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 9
        Job Counters
                Failed map tasks=4
                Launched map tasks=4
                Other local map tasks=3
                Rack-local map tasks=1
```

Any help .

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the issue resolved . 
It was because the driver and connection managers information was not specified in sqoop export statement . Also the jar that Sqoop used did not support upsert to target .

Used a custom jar that supports upsert's to target and it worked.

`sqoop-export -D mapred.job.name=SQOOP:TEST:UPSERT -Dsqoop.export.records.per.statement=1 --connect $CONN --username $USER --password $PWD --table table_test_1 --hcatalog-database default --hcatalog-table test_1 --input-fields-terminated-by '\001' --input-null-string '\\N' --update-key ID --update-mode allowinsert --verbose --columns "name,id,age" --driver net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver --connection-manager com.custom.sqoop.manager.SQLServerManager`